# Query Optimization (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

Summary:

We have a page of products and users comments that may or may not exist on each product. One table holds the product details (products_master), one table determines which product will be displayed (shoppingfeed). As we loop and output each product from query #1, query #2 is executed to pull associated comments with the current product being displayed from query #1.

Problem:
This all works, but it's SLOW! We are thinking if there is a way to combine this into one optimized query that we can execute once, and then loop through it... or any other ideas to make this faster.

Query #1

```
 SELECT shoppingfeed.action_date,
       products_master.name,
       products_master.image_url,
       products_master.pop_sku,
       products_master.group_id,
       products_master.lowest_price,
       products_master.highest_price,
       products_master.merchant,
       products_master.width,
       products_master.height
FROM   products_master,
       shoppingfeed
WHERE  ( shoppingfeed.sf_product_id = products_master.pop_sku )
ORDER  BY action_date DESC
LIMIT  #offset#, #maxrow#
```

Query #2

```
 SELECT DISTINCT comment,
                comment_id,
                comments.user_id,
                comment_date_time,
                comment_visibility,
                comments.friend_user_id,
                thread_id,
                alias,
                first_name,
                last_name,
                action_id,
                group_id,
                users.fb_resource_id,
                gender,
                acct_type,
                ascore
FROM   comments,
       users,
       products_master,
       user_relationship
WHERE  comments.sf_product_id = #feed_item.pop_sku#
       AND comments.user_id = users.user_id
       AND products_master.pop_sku = #feed_item.pop_sku#
       AND ( ( comments.user_id = user_relationship.sf_id
               AND user_relationship.user_id = #SESSION.user_id#
               AND user_relationship.relationship_status = 3 )
              OR ( comments.user_id = #session.user_id#
                   AND user_relationship.user_id = #SESSION.user_id#
                   AND user_relationship.relationship_status = 99 ) )
ORDER  BY comment_date_time ASC
```

Here is the view I put together

> select `products_master`.`pop_sku` AS
>   `pop_sku`,`products_master`.`group_id` AS
>   `group_id`,`products_master`.`name` AS
>   `name`,`products_master`.`image_url` AS
>   `image_url`,`products_master`.`last_updated` AS
>   `last_updated`,`products_master`.`have_it_users` AS
>   `have_it_users`,`products_master`.`want_it_users` AS
>   `want_it_users`,`products_master`.`adults_only` AS
>   `adults_only`,`products_master`.`reviewed_by` AS
>   `reviewed_by`,`products_master`.`donate_needed_qty` AS
>   `donate_needed_qty`,`products_master`.`inspired_users` AS
>   `inspired_users`,`products_master`.`deal_users_up` AS
>   `deal_users_up`,`products_master`.`deal_users_down` AS
>   `deal_users_down`,`products_master`.`merchant` AS
>   `merchant`,`products_master`.`merchant_logo` AS
>   `merchant_logo`,`products_master`.`width` AS
>   `width`,`products_master`.`height` AS
>   `height`,`products_master`.`added_by` AS
>   `added_by`,`products_master`.`product_category_id` AS
>   `product_category_id`,`comments`.`comment` AS
>   `comment`,`comments`.`comment_date_time` AS
>   `comment_date_time`,`comments`.`comment_visibility` AS
>   `comment_visibility`,`comments`.`friend_user_id` AS
>   `friend_user_id`,`comments`.`user_id` AS
>   `user_id`,`comments`.`action_id` AS
>   `action_id`,`comments`.`comment_id` AS
>   `comment_id`,`shoppingfeed`.`action_code` AS
>   `action_code`,`shoppingfeed`.`action_date` AS
>   `action_date`,`shoppingfeed`.`new_friend_id` AS
>   `new_friend_id`,`shoppingfeed`.`question_id` AS
>   `question_id`,`users`.`first_name` AS `first_name`,`users`.`last_name`
>   AS `last_name`,`users`.`shopping_clout` AS
>   `shopping_clout`,`users`.`gender` AS `gender`,`users`.`fb_resource_id`
>   AS `fb_resource_id`,`comments`.`thread_id` AS
>   `thread_id`,`users`.`wish_qty` AS `wish_qty`,`merchants`.`logo` AS
>   `logo`,`merchants`.`companyname` AS
>   `companyname`,`product_relationship`.`desirability` AS `desirability`
>   from (((((`products_master` join `shoppingfeed`
>   on((`products_master`.`pop_sku` = `shoppingfeed`.`sf_product_id`)))
>   join `comments` on((`products_master`.`pop_sku` =
>   `comments`.`sf_product_id`))) join `users` on(((`comments`.`user_id` =
>   `users`.`user_id`) and (`comments`.`user_id` =
>   `shoppingfeed`.`user_id`)))) join `product_relationship`
>   on((`product_relationship`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id`))) join
>   `merchants` on(((`products_master`.`merchant` =
>   `merchants`.`merchantid`) and (`product_relationship`.`sf_product_id`
>   = `products_master`.`pop_sku`)))) order by `comments`.`comment_date_time`

Comment: What happens when you try to run it as one query?  Also, to help tune it, we'll need the SHOW CREATE TABLE and EXPLAIN output.

Comment: I am no expert, I created a view and it seems to be much faster... I am sure it's not perfect.  Look above for the view I put together

Comment: If you want us to help optimize a query, **you need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. try to use 'inner join' or 'left/right join' instead of conditions in 'where' clause
2. check your primary key and foreign key,add it to your table columns if they refers more in join table
3. create index for your table columns if they refers more in join table(in fact,foreign key is one of the index)

Answer (score 0):

I added some indexes, and made a view, now things are cooking.  I am gonna experiment with a couple more indexes to make it even faster, but I am a happy camper right now.